# Where to Define Constants with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, constants

I have a few genuine constants that I would like to use in Zend Framework.  I know I can set them in the index.php but this is not executed when running PHPUnit tests.  (Not in this case, anyhow).

How else can I set these within the framework?  The problem is that constants need to be declared outside the class.  (I don't want class constants).

If all else fails, I can set them in my unit testing bootstrap, but I'd like to avoid the duplication if possible.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805965/php-zend-framework-zend-config-and-global-state?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always define them in the bootstrap file. But i do use the Zend_Registry instead of constants.

```
Zend_Registry::set('property1', 'value1');

//everywhere in your code
$value = Zend_Registry::get('property1');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that you can define "real" constants in your `application.ini` file.
Example:

```
//application.ini
[production]
constants.ONE = 'HELLO'
constants.TWO = 'WORLD'


//Bootstrap.php
public function setConstants($constants)
{
    // define() is notoriously slow
    if (function_exists('apc_define_constants')) {
        apc_define_constants('zf', $constants);
        return;
    }

    foreach ($constants as $name => $value) {
        if (false === defined($name)) {
            define($name, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom library and define all your constants there.
It will be beneficial to you, as library called each time when you call the controller.

You have to need to define the custom library in bootstrap and ini file.

This will be a good practice because every constants you can find at a place and you can make changes easily whenever you want.